# C# if statement shorthand operators (? :) results in unreachable code

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, if-statement

Why do I get this warning in C# with Visual Studio 2010?

```
"Unreachable expression code detected"
```

from the following code (`DateTime.Now` underlined in green squiggly):

```
public DateTime StartDate
{
  get
  {
    DateTime dt = (DateTime)ViewState["StartDate"];
    return ((dt == null) ? DateTime.Now : dt);
  }
}
```

Comment: Okay, because `DateTime` is a structure and can never be `null`.  So what value so I check for in my `ViewState` is empty?

Comment: `Unreachable expression` sounds fairly close to `Always evaluates to (TRUE|FALSE)`...are you sure `dt` could be `null`?  Or does classic `if {} else {}` work fine?

Comment: Typos: So what value should I check for in case my `ViewState` is empty?

Comment: What an awesome compiler! Thank you compiler :)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Because a DateTime struct can never be null.

If you're expecting a possible null value, you have to use a nullable DateTime struct. You could also use the null-coalescing operator instead of the conditional operator as well:

```
public DateTime StartDate
{
    get
    {
        DateTime? dt = (DateTime?)ViewState["StartDate"];
        return dt ?? DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

Or you could do it as a one-liner (as in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505703/c-if-statement-shorthand-operators-results-in-unreachable-code#comment-3663733)):

```
public DateTime StartDate
{
    get { return (DateTime)(ViewState["StartDate"] ?? DateTime.Now); }
}
```

Comment: So what happens if the "StartDate" key doesn't exist?

Comment: @Blam: In ASP.NET, if the ViewState key does not exists, you get `null`. I often express the same thing as @Justin with a one-liner: `return (DateTime)(ViewState["StartDate"] ?? DateTime.Now);`. Works like a charm.

Comment: @Blam: I was just in the process of asking that myself!  @Justin: great solution, thanks!

Comment: @Blam: if StartDate doesn't exist dt will be null and the coalescing operator (??) will then return the right side (DateTime.Now)

Comment: I didn't think `return dt ?? DateTime.Now;` would compile, since `dt` is `Nullable<DateTime>` and the return type is `DateTime`. However, that gets compiled to the equivalent of `return dt.HasValue ? dt.GetValueOrDefault() : DateTime.Now;`. Interesting.

Comment: @Anthony: The rules for determining exactly what the result type of the null coalescing operator is are pretty complicated, but usually result in the sensible thing. After all, the intention of the operator is to *eliminate nulls*, so we want to go to the non-nullable type if we can possibly get away with it. See the language spec for details.

Answer (score 4):

DateTime is a value type, so it can never be null.  Therefore, the test for == null evaluates to a constant false at compile time, so half of the ?: will never be reached at runtime.

Answer (score 4):

The answers given already -- that a non-nullable value type will never be null, and therefore the comparison is known to return false at compile time -- are correct, you might be wondering about the obvious follow-up question: why is this even *legal*? That question has been asked many times on SO; the short version is that C# provides a "lifted" equality operator for every struct that provides an equality operator on the non-nullable type (if a lifted one does not exist already of course.)

That is to say, because DateTime provides an == operator, the compiler automatically generates an == operator on DateTime?, and *that* operator is applicable in your case.

Comment: Another frequently asked question. Why does the compiler forget to issue the other warning, _The result of the expression is always 'false' since a value of type 'System.DateTime' is never equal to 'null' of type 'System.DateTime?'_. This warning works (at least most of the type) of lifted built-in equality operators `==`, like in `42 == null`, but will not work for user-defined operators `==` like the one on `DateTime`, when they are lifted.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: The missing warning was a bug; I suspect I introduced it in C# 3. When I was at Microsoft it was never a high enough priority for me to investigate it fully; I don't know whether it was fixed in Roslyn or not. I regret the error.

Answer (score 3):

That could be because `DateTime` is a struct (value type) & not a reference type.
Hence, comparing it with null will always be false.

Answer (score 1):

DateTime cannot be null

Answer (score 1):

DateTime is not nullable, so its value will never be null.